# Highcharts bubble chart "select points" not functioning

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

Today my highcharts bubble chart stopped allowing me to select the bubbles: it was working through yesterday. Here is the code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

title: {
    text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: {
        text: 'Daily fat intake'
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} gr'
    }
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Daily sugar intake'
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} gr'
    },
    maxPadding: 0.2
},



plotOptions: {
    series: { allowPointSelect: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [
        { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
        { x: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
        { x: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'FI', country: 'Finland' },
        { x: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'NL', country: 'Netherlands' },
        { x: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'SE', country: 'Sweden' },
        { x: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'ES', country: 'Spain' },
        { x: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'FR', country: 'France' },
        { x: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'NO', country: 'Norway' },
        { x: 71, y: 93.2, z: 24.7, name: 'UK', country: 'United Kingdom' },
        { x: 69.2, y: 57.6, z: 10.4, name: 'IT', country: 'Italy' },
        { x: 68.6, y: 20, z: 16, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
        { x: 65.5, y: 126.4, z: 35.3, name: 'US', country: 'United States' },
        { x: 65.4, y: 50.8, z: 28.5, name: 'HU', country: 'Hungary' },
        { x: 63.4, y: 51.8, z: 15.4, name: 'PT', country: 'Portugal' },
        { x: 64, y: 82.9, z: 31.3, name: 'NZ', country: 'New Zealand' }
    ]
}]
```

});

I recreated the problem in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/azq5nx8a/

Interestingly, if you enable dataLabels, then you can select the point by clicking on the data label. But even with dataLabels enabled, just clicking on the bubble and not the label does nothing (unless you've already selected the bubble using the data label: if you start in that state, you can select and deselect the bubble by just clicking on the bubble. Play around and see).

On Github it looks like there was an update last night related to bubble charts. I wonder if that caused this issue.

Can anyone get this to work, so the bubbles can be selected by clicking on the bubble and not a data label?

Comment: It looks like a bug in 5.0.11 version (released yesterday). Workaround: Use 5.0.10 version: http://jsfiddle.net/azq5nx8a/1/ It's already reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6685

Comment: Yes, I went back to 5.0.10 and it works. Thanks!